# update value in file(web.config) present on another machine(shared folder/network) using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, automation

I have full access to the file present on another machine and while I type

`\\username-txd\abcFolder\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config`

In run command line I am able to access the above mentioned file but when I try to update the value of any attribute in this particular file it is not allowing me to update.

```
public void updateFileData(string elementKey, string newElementValue)
{
    // xmlDoc.Load("\\vinayb2-txd\\atish\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config");
    // var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@filename);
    // string serverFilepath= Server.MapPath(@filename);
    // FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    // xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
    // string abc=new Uri(filename).LocalPath;

    xmlDoc.Load(@filename);
    XmlNodeList elementList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("add");

    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (elementList[i].Attributes["key"].Value == elementKey)
        {
            elementList[i].Attributes["value"].Value = newElementValue;
            break;
        }

        xmlDoc.Save(abc);
    }
}
```

when I am passing the value to `xmlDoc.Load(@filename);`

The filename is displayed as the passed value which I want. But as soon as I move ahead with debugging the code, I see my filepath gets appended with the `d:/` value.

And then the filename becomes

```
filename="D:\\username-txd\abcFolder\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config"
```

Why does `D://` get appended, is it referring my local `D` drive?

Commented lines are some of the option I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to add an extra pair of backslashes before the hostname.
Not `\\hostname` but `\\\\hostname`.

So in your case `\\\\vinayb2-txd\\atish\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Markus.. now I am able to load the file

Comment: But Now, XmlNodeList elementList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("add");

Value of elementList is not the numeric value.. It's giving value as {System.Xml.XmlElementList}

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer helped you please give it an upvote and mark it as correct.

Comment: And please post any further issues as a different question.